# cascading dropdown changing templates

Tags: angularjs, cascadingdropdown

ifound at angularjs: cascade dropdown - the following

`<link href="http://jsfiddle.net/6eCZC/1/">demo</link>`

Can anybody tell me how to include html-templates depending on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
           templateUrl: '/landing.html'
       })
       .when('/login', {  // Login page/folder
           templateUrl: '/app/login/login.view.html',
           controller: 'Login as vm',
           css : '/app/login/login.css'
       });
```

this helps in redirecting to the correct template to fill up ng-view. After this you can just use
    $location.href = '#templateName'
in your ng-change function to redirect to the correct template.

Comment: Is it possible write the url like this:  id: 1, name: "client1", departments: [{ id: 1, defaultLabel: 'department1', url:'template.html'}, { id: 2, defaultLabel: 'department2', url:'template2.html'}] }, ?

Comment: Yes you can do it this way as well... with a little tweak in what I have shown.. just put the nth item url value for templateUrl field... and we should be good to go.